# Simple Panel Script from not working, closing script tag incorrect?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, footer

Below is a script that I am using and has always worked, however lately in my wordpress site, dreamweaver is picking up the closing tag as incorrect? Is all my mark up below correct?

I haven't changed anything, but now it's playing up, I cannot work out the problem?

```
<script>
        $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        // perform JavaScript after the document is scriptable.
        $j(document).ready(function() {
        // setup ul.tabs to work as tabs for each div directly under div.panes
        $j("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div#panel");
    });
    </script>
```

Whole Page of Code:

```
    <div class="footer">
    <p>
    <ul class="details">
    <li><span><b>&copy; Uni Compare Ltd</b></span></li>
    <li><span><a href="http://universitycompare.com/terms-and-conditions/">Terms and conditions</a></span></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="socialnav">
    <li><span><a href="http://ucas.com/"><img alt="UCAS" src="/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/addedimages/ucas_soc.png"  /></a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href="https://twitter.com/#!/unicompare"><img alt="Twitter" src="/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/addedimages/twitter_soc.png"  /></a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/University-Compare/197132243631509"><img alt="Facebook" src="/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/addedimages/facebook_soc.png"  /></a></span></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
    <div id="btmlinks">

    <ul>
    <li><b>Site links</b></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/university-guide/">University guide</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/student-info/">Student Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="mailto:letstalk@universitycompare.com?subject=Advertisement%20Enquiry">Contact for Advertisement</a></li>
    <li><a href="mailto:info@universitycompare.com">Contact us</a></li>
    <li style="text-indent:-9999px;">University Compare - Your future online</li>
    </ul> 

    <ul>
    <li><b>Top universities</b></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/university-guide/cambridge-university">Cambridge, University of</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/university-guide/university-of-oxford/">Oxford, University of</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/university-guide/london-school-of-economics/">London School of Economics</a></li>
    </ul>  

    <ul>
    <li><b>Our Partners</b></li>
    <li><a href="http://stustu.co.uk">Stustu.co.uk</a></li>    
    <li><a href="http://www.purepotential.org/">Pure Potential</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>  

    </div>

<!-- UC UNI PAGE CSS TABS SCRIPT  -->
<script>
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    // perform JavaScript after the document is scriptable.
    $j(document).ready(function() {
    // setup ul.tabs to work as tabs for each div directly under div.panes
    $j("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div#panel");
});
</script>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<!-- Main Page Table Sorted -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<?php if (is_page( array(2502, 15))) : ?>
<!-- JavaScript includes -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/assets/countdown/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/assets/js/script.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added the whole page script, strangely, when I put a closing script tag before the opening script tag, it seems to be seen as normal and dreamweaver doesn't see it as a problem.

Comment: getting no errors here

Comment: @mark I've updated my answers with all the code on the page just incase it helps anyone?

Comment: If nothing else, at the very top of the complete script, you have an opening `<p>` that isn't closed.

Comment: can you show your webpage link?

Answer (score 0):

In the whole page of code, you have a `<p>` paragraph tag that starts below `<div class="footer">`. You never closed the paragraph with `</p>`.

You can either close it with `</p>` before `</div>` but not inside of `<ul> </ul>`

or

delete the opening `<p>` tag.

The script you posted above seems fine to me.